# wxFrame with title bar but non resizable

Tags: python, wxpython

hai guyz

I need to create a login window 
for that window i need a title bar for dragging but it should not be a resized
I need a fixed size for this window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame = wx.Frame(self, title="something", size=(480, 320), style=wx.CAPTION)
```

You can "mix and match" styles, which can be seen here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxframe.html

e.g. in my example, no "close box" is shown, so:

```
frame = wx.Frame(self, title="something", size=(480, 320), style=wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
```

would fix it. (Note: you need wx.SOMETHING, not wxSOMETHING)